# problems running logstash with -f flag in docker

Tags: docker, logstash, redhat

I'm trying to run the logstash container in red hat 7 with the command:

```
docker run -v /home/logstash/config:/conf -v /home/docker/logs:/logs logstash logstash -f /conf/logstash.conf --verbose
```

and the response received is:

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-05-05T10:21:20.765000+0000", :message=>"translation missing: en.logstash.runner.configuration.file-not-found", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-05-05T10:21:20.770000+0000", :message=>"starting agent", :level=>:info}
```

and the logstash container is not running.

If I execute the folowing command:

```
docker run -dit -v /home/logstash/config:/conf -v /home/docker/logs:/logs --name=logstash2 logstash logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout { } }'
```

Enter in the container with the command :

```
docker exec -ti bash
```

and execute:

```
logstash -f /conf/logstash.conf
```

A new logstash proccess is now running in the container and I can manage log files setted up in the config file.

Any idea why am i having this strange behaviour?

Thanks, for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was a directory permissions in the host machine.Thanks for helping @NOTtardy

Answer (score 0):

<del>Try making double quotes around `logstash -f /conf/logstash.conf --verbose`</del>

---

Edit: just tried you command myself and it works fine. Could be that your logstash.conf is the reason for the error.

I've used a very simple logstash.conf

```
input {
    udp {
        port => 5000
        type => syslog
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

And got the following output

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-05-05T18:24:26.294000+0000", :message=>"starting agent", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2016-05-05T18:24:26.332000+0000", :message=>"starting pipeline", :id=>"main", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2016-05-05T18:24:26.370000+0000", :message=>"Starting UDP listener", :address=>"0.0.0.0:5000", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2016-05-05T18:24:26.435000+0000", :message=>"Starting pipeline", :id=>"main", :pipeline_workers=>1, :batch_size=>125, :batch_delay=>5, :max_inflight=>125, :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2016-05-05T18:24:26.441000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline main started"}
```

Comment: It's not working, the message error now is "/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /logstash -f /conf/logstash.conf --verbose: No such file or directory". I'm using logstash latest official image.

Comment: Looks like you have "/logstash -f ..." but it should be "logstash -f ..."

Comment: the command executed is docker run -v /home/logstash/config:/conf -v /home/docker/logs:/logs logstash "logstash -f /conf/logstash.conf --verbose". There isn't a "/" before the logstash command.

Comment: I try the nex command docker run -v /home/logstash/config:/conf -v /home/docker/logs:/logs logstash "logstash" "-f" "/conf/logstash.conf" "--verbose" and I obteined the first error, file not found.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a directory permissions in the host machine.Thanks for helping @NOTtardy